# Jest not terminating after tests complete successfully

Tags: javascript, jestjs, supertest

I'm working with `jest` & `supertest` to test my api endpoints and the tests are passing with no problems; however `jest` is never exiting with the *Done in X amount of time* statement that I would normally see. I looked to make sure the `--watch` flag was not being used and it was not. It seems as if the connection to the server is never ending so `jest` is left wondering what is next. `UserFactory.generate()` creates fake user data using the `faker` library.

I'm at a loss on trying to troubleshoot this. I've followed the recommended strategies on `jest`'s help page with no luck and been digging around in the issue tracker as well but see nothing about similar issues.

This is what I will see on running my test suite:

[image]

As you can see the test is ran 7 passes. I'm told that all tests have been run and then `morgan` shows the `POST` that has happened. `jest` never *exits* so in reality this is failing because it will timeout on any CI sever barring a manual exit.

I have tried using `.end() & done()` as well as `.then() & done()` in place of the `async/await`. They all are returning the same end result and if it were an issue of a promise not resolving `jest` will error out over an unresolved promise so I am beyond stumped on why this is not terminating as `jest` normally would.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before?

*user.controller.test.js*

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import request from 'supertest';
import { UserFactory } from '../../__mocks__';
import { User } from '../../modules';
import { config } from '../../utils';
import app from '../../';

const mockRoute = data => request(app).post(`${config.ENDPOINT}/user/sign-up`).send(data);

describe(`POST: /user/sign-up`, () => {
  // remove any user data from db prior to running tests.
  beforeAll(async () => { await User.remove(); });
  test('Returns status 201 on success.', async () => {
    // Returns the response object: res.status === { status }
    const { status }  = await mockRoute(UserFactory.generate());
    expect(status).toEqual(201);
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    // drop connection to the collection
    const { users } = mongoose.connection.collections;
    await users.drop();
  });
});
```

*user/routes.js*

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import validate from 'express-validation';

import { signUp } from './controller';
import valid from './validation'

const routes = new Router();

/**
 * 1. Define the route: 'user/signup'.
 * 2. Validate the data being provided on the POST
 *    against valid.signUp object.
 * 3. Provide data to signUp controller method for
 *    creating a user in the database.
 */
 routes.post('/user/sign-up', validate(valid.signUp), signUp);

 export default routes;
```

*user/controller.js*

```
import HTTPStatus from 'http-status';
import User from './model';
import { config, filterBody } from '../../utils';

export const signUp = async (req, res, next) => {
  const filteredBody = filterBody(req.body, config.WHITELIST.users.signUp);
  try {
    const user = await User.create(filteredBody);
    return res.status(HTTPStatus.CREATED).json(user.toAuthJSON());
  } catch (e) {
    e.status = HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    return next(e);
  }
}
```

*user/model.js*

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator';
import { hashSync, compareSync } from 'bcrypt-nodejs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import { config } from '../../utils';

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, 'Email is required!'],
    trim: true,
    validate: {
      validator(email) {
        const emailRegex = /^[-a-z0-9%S_+]+(\.[-a-z0-9%S_+]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[a-z]{2,63}$/i;
        return emailRegex.test(email);
      },
      message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email!',
    }
   },
   password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Password is required!'],
      trim: true,
      minlength: [6, 'Password need to be longer!'],
      validate: {
        validator(password) {
        return password.length >= 6 && password.match(/\d+/g);
        },
      },
  }
}, { timestamps: true })

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {
  message: '{VALUE} already taken!',
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (this.isModified('password')) {
   this.password = this._hashPassword(this.password);
   return next();
  }
  return next();
});


UserSchema.methods = {
  authenticateUser(password) {
    return compareSync(password, this.password);
  },
  _hashPassword(password) {
    return hashSync(password);
  },
  createToken() {
    return jwt.sign({ _id: this._id }, config.JWT_SECRET);
  },
  toAuthJSON() {
    return {
      _id: this._id,
      token: `JWT ${this.createToken()}`,
    };
  },
  toJSON() {
    return {
      _id: this._id,
      username: this.username,
    };
  },
};

let User;

try {
   User = mongoose.model('User');
} catch (e) {
   User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
}

export default User;
```

*user/validation.js*

```
import Joi from 'joi';

export default {
   signUp: {
    body: {
      email: Joi.string().email().required(),
      password: Joi.string()
        .min(6)
        .regex(/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/)
        .required(),
    },
  },
};
```

*middlewares.js*

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import compression from 'compression';
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import { userRoutes } from '../modules';

export default app => {
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  // applying api routes last.
  app.use('/api/v1', [userRoutes]);
}
```

*index.js*

```
import express from 'express';
import {
  database,
  config,
  middlewares,
} from './utils';

// Create instance of Express.
const app = express();
const MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV;

// Apply middlewares to Express.
middlewares(app);
// Connect to the environment determined database.
database(config.MONGO_URI)

app.listen(config.PORT, err => {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  console.log(`App running on port: ${config.PORT} in ${MODE} mode.`);
});

export default app;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured out the issue was that I was not doing enough in the `afterAll()` hook.

I made a small repo to reproduce the issue and troubleshoot it from there and this was what needed to be done so that `jest` could exit on successful completion of the test suite:

```
afterAll(async () => {
try {
  const { todos } = mongoose.connection.collections;
  // Collection is being dropped.
  await todos.drop()
  // Connection to Mongo killed.
  await mongoose.disconnect();
  // Server connection closed.
  await server.close();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`
    You did something wrong dummy!
    ${error}
  `);
  throw error;
}
```

Comment: I would like to add as well that there is no need the `unlock()` the modules here. It was just an issue of the database connection still being open and preventing `jest` from exiting with 0.

Comment: for me doing `await mongoose.disconnect();` was enough. I am not running `server.close();`. 
Also, in case anyone else (like me) has more than one connection (opened with `createConnection()` rather than `connect()`) you just need one `mongoose.disconnect();` rather than `connection1.disconnect()` & `conneciton2.disconnect()`

Comment: where are you getting the object 'server' in line 8 from?

Answer (score 3):

My setup has `supertest` and `mongodb-memory-server`.

None of the techniques advised here solved the problem for me.

`mongodb-memory-server` connection ends when it runs alone. But when i combine it with `supertest` jest doesnt terminate. And jest doesnt show up any open handle error either.

Jest terminated with success only after I did run with `--forceExit` command.

https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--forceexit

Comment: Okay. But where do I add `--forceExit` in my code?

Answer (score -2):

this is what it worked for me:

```
afterAll(async () => {
    try {
      // Connection to Mongo killed.
      await mongoose.disconnect();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`
        You did something wrong dummy!
        ${error}
      `);
      throw error;
    }
});
```